# Why can't I concurrently load ReportDocuments in Crystal

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Using the code below we run into an issue with Crystal.

It seems ok to create ReportDocuments but not to load these simultaneously (DESPITE the fact they are loaded from different PHYSICAL places)

It works fine with the lock in place, but remove that lock and it freezes!!

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
public static object fLock = new object();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] i = { 1, 2, 3 };
    Parallel.ForEach<int>(i, j => CreateReportOutput(j));
}

private void CreateReportOutput(int j)
{
     CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rpt = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();

     **lock (fLock)**
         rpt.Load(string.Format("C:\\_Temp\\temptabs\\reports{0:00}\\C_NOTES.RFM", j));

     rpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, string.Format("C:\\_Temp\\temptabs\\output_{0}({1:00}).pdf", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_fff"), j));
}
```

Comment: What language and version is the above code in? CR has SDK in several different languages and versions.

Comment: Crystal 10.5 - Visual Studio version - language above is C#

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well, except for the fact that I don't explicitly parallelize it, but it's caused when I click the button a second time when the first report is loading. `Load` seems to be asynchronous by itself.